# Terraform BigQuery table creation with schema - Error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field TableFieldSchema.type of type string

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create a `BigQuery` table using the below schema via `Terraform`. But receiving the below error.
This is part of code for for pubsub push to bq subscription and bq table creation via `terraform`.

Error:

```
Error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field TableFieldSchema.type of type string
with module.pubsub["b"].google_bigquery_table.bq_table[0],
on ../../modules/main.tf line 82, in resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_table":
  82: resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_table" {
```

Terraform:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_table" {
  deletion_protection = false
  table_id            = var.topic_config.bq_table
  dataset_id          = var.topic_config.bq_dataset
  schema              = var.topic_config.bq_table_schema
}
```

Schema:

```
[ 
   {   "name": "SalesDate",   "type": ["int", "null"] }, 
   {   "name": "SaleFiscalYearWeek",   "type": ["string", "null"] }, 
   {   "name": "CostOfSalesLocalCurrency",   "type": [{
    "type": "bytes",
    "logicalType": "decimal",
    "precision": 38,
    "scale": 6   }, "null"] }]
```

Terraform variables topic_config value is:

```
topic_config = {   
  "b" = {
    topic_name                 = "g-b-topic"
    message_retention_duration = "1200s"
    has_schema                 = true
    topic_schema_path    = "schema/twitter.avsc"
    schema_name          = "b-schema"
    message_encoding     = "JSON"
    subscription_name    = "g-b-push-sub"
    subscription_type    = "push_to_bq"
    ack_deadline_seconds = 600
    bq_dataset           = "streaming"
    bq_exsiting_ds_flag  = false
    bq_table             = "push_to_bq_table"
    bq_source_format     = "AVRO"
    bq_table_schema      = <<EOF [ 
   {   "name": "SalesDate",   "type": ["int", "null"] }, 
   {   "name": "SaleFiscalYearWeek",   "type": ["string", "null"] }, 
   {   "name": "CostOfSalesLocalCurrency",   "type": [{
    "type": "bytes",
    "logicalType": "decimal",
    "precision": 38,
    "scale": 6   }, "null"] }] EOF
    use_topic_schema     = true
    write_metadata       = false
    drop_unknown_fields  = false   }, }
```

Comment: This usually implies a JSON formatting error. You should probably try structuring the schema as HCL2 and then converting to JSON with `jsonencode` to avoid the formatting issues.

Comment: Hi @Eves, did the answer resolve your issue?

Comment: no it didnt help..

Comment: Hi @Eves, can you try by changing the schema?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to configure your `topic_config` in a `Json` file.

The Terraform project structure become :

[image]

Your project contains the `topic_config` `Terraform` module :

```
your_project
      topic_config
```

The `Json` file is :

```json
{
  "topic_config": {
    "b": {
      "topic_name": "g-b-topic",
      "message_retention_duration": "1200s",
      "has_schema": true,
      "topic_schema_path": "schema/twitter.avsc",
      "schema_name": "b-schema",
      "message_encoding": "JSON",
      "subscription_name": "g-b-push-sub",
      "subscription_type": "push_to_bq",
      "ack_deadline_seconds": 600,
      "bq_dataset": "streaming",
      "bq_exsiting_ds_flag": false,
      "bq_table": "push_to_bq_table",
      "bq_source_format": "AVRO",
      "bq_schema_path": "topic_config.json",
      "use_topic_schema": true,
      "write_metadata": false,
      "drop_unknown_fields": false
    }
  }
}
```

I separated the `BigQuery` table schema in a file under : `topic_config/resource/schema/topic_config.json` and the previous configuration gives the path to this schema.

You can then retrieve this config from `locals.tf` file using `jsondecode` and `file` functions :

```
locals {
  topic_config = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resource/topic_config.json"))["topic_config"]
}
```

Your `main.tf` file :

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_table" {
  for_each            = local.topic_config
  deletion_protection = false
  table_id            = each.value["bq_table"]
  dataset_id          = each.value["bq_dataset"]
  schema              = file("${path.module}/resource/schema/${each.value["schema_path"]}")
}
```

- The `topic_config` from local variable is a `Map`
- We added a `for_each` on `topic_config`
- We access to the fields with `each.value["field_name"]`
- The `BQ` schema access to `{current_module}/resource/schema/{configured_path}`

Comment: @eves have your solved your issue ?